# Помогите написать запрос с элокентом

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Помогите написать элокент
Запрос на mysql

```
SELECT * from `products` where title like 'Закуски' OR title like 'Канапе';
```

С элокентом я написал, но выводит ошибку

```
$categories = Category::where('title', 'title' ,'LIKE', '%' 'Канапе' '%' , 'OR', 'title', 'LIKE','%' 'Закуски''%')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$categories = Category::where('title', 'like', '%Закуски%')->orWhere('title', 'like', '%Канапе%')->get();
```